# Unexpected end of input (at character 2)

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-getx

`

I'm trying to get the data from api using getx state management

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:e_sante/Data/User.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Controller extends GetxController{
  var patientList=<Patient>[].obs;
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  @override
  void onInit(){
    super.onInit();
    fetchPatientData();
  }
  Future<void> fetchPatientData() async{
    final response= await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/patients?Ip=C123456'));
    if(response.statusCode==200){

      for(var i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++){
        Patient patient= Patient.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body[i]));

        patientList.add(Patient(
            Ip: patient.Ip,
            Nom: patient.Nom,
            Age: patient.Age,
            Mail: patient.Mail,
            Tel: patient.Tel,
            Password: patient.Password),
        );

      }
      isLoading.value=true;

    }else{
      Get.snackbar('Error loading data!', 'Sever responded: ${response.statusCode}:${response.reasonPhrase.toString()}');
    }

  }
}
```

```
class Patient{
    final String Ip,Nom,Mail,Password;
   final int Age,Tel;
  Patient({
    required this.Ip,
    required this.Nom,
    required this.Age,
    required this.Mail,
    required this.Tel,
    required this.Password
  });
  factory Patient.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return Patient(
        Ip: json['Ip'],
        Nom: json['Nom'],
        Age: json['Age'],
        Mail: json['Mail'],
        Tel: json['Tel'],
        Password: json['Password']
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'Data/controller.dart';

class ControllerBindings extends Bindings{ @override void dependencies() { Get.put<Controller>(Controller()); } }
```

when I'm hot reloading my app I encountered this error ( Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>') and when I open the screen who should display the data the screen keeps loading[image: Error screen]

`

Comment: what do you want? stop loading or fix data mapping?

Comment: the error is self explanatory. You try to read the response as a single Patient object, but it sees a list (of what I assume Patient objects).

Comment: @Taz honestly I'm trying to solve both I think fixing the data mapping would stop the loading problem

Answer (score 3):

According to your error message, it looks like your api return list of json object but you are try to map this list of json object to an json object. Try to map the response to list of json then may be it will work.

```
List<Patient> patientsFromJson(String body) =>
    List<Patient>.from(jsonDecode(body).map((x) => Patient.fromJson(x)));
```

Then use this patientsFromJson to map the api response

```
Future<void> fetchPatientData() async{
    final response= await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:3000/patients?Ip=C123456'));

    if(response.statusCode==200){
      var patients = patientsFromJson(response.body);

      for (var patient in patients) {
        patientList.add(patient);
      }

     // patientList.addAll(patients);
      isLoading.value=true;
    }else{
      Get.snackbar('Error loading data!', 'Sever responded: ${response.statusCode}:${response.reasonPhrase.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

Comment: after making these changes it shows the same error in a different way (Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int')

Comment: Can you post your api response, so that I can understand which type or filed gives error?

Comment: I'm working currently with a fake api for testing my app while the guy I'm working with finishes his work, the api accepts any sort of data posted on the localhost. the error could be from the localhost or its not a problem??

Comment: I think this is api response and dart model class conversion problem that means your api response data format and dart model class data format are not same currently.

Answer (score 0):

1.fundamental error resolution
The response.body is List but you add into Map, so you can change this

```
for(var i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++){
     Patient patient= Patient.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body[i]));
     patientList.add(Patient(
          Ip: patient.Ip,
          Nom: patient.Nom,
          Age: patient.Age,
          Mail: patient.Mail,
          Tel: patient.Tel,
          Password: patient.Password),
      );

}
```

2.expect it to stop the loading when If an error occurs
You have to catch error and stop loading but the error occurs can't catch in Future.
so try this

```
//somewhere 
fetchPatientData().then(processValue).catchError(handleError);
```

refer to https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Comment: a new error when I tried the solution you gave me